# How to center a navbar on a different resolution?

Tags: html, css, center, navbar

So after hours of searching I still can't find the fix for me stupidity, I'm new to this but on my main monitor it centers just fine

1920x1080:
[Larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/encpB.jpg)

But will my 1280x1024:
[Smaller image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWshK.jpg)

So as you can see it's uncomfortably off balanced so here's my code for the website..

```css
/*---Start Navbar---*/

.nav-main {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  /* Adds shadow to the bottom of the bar */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
  /* Adds the transparent background */
  background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.8);
  color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.8);
}
.nav-logo {
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  line-height: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  left: 30%;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
ul li {
  float: inherit;
}
.nav-item {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  height: 40px;
  width: auto;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}
/*---End Navbar---*/
```

```html
<nav class="nav-main">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="http://phalanxgaming.org/" class="nav-logo" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/sg5DZao.png?2" alt="logo" style="width:60px;height:60px;">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1ukgWHC3_xFmkxiCEhb-ZN9dYw2kHWQEyo_inPW7u0mw/viewform?usp=send_form" class="nav-item" target="_blank">CONTACT US</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="ts3server://tsgb1.vilayer.com:10022/?nickname=" class="nav-item">TEAMSPEAK</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.paypal.me/PhalanxGaming" class="nav-item" target="_blank">DONATE</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://steamcommunity.com/groups/P-GC" class="nav-item" target="_blank">STEAM</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://www.twitch.tv/phalanxgamingofficial/" class="nav-item">TWITCH</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Any and all support is great, ps sorry for slurring I'm quite tired and I couldn't sleep til I fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is, to display your list elements inline. So set up

```
ul li {
/*  float: inherit; */
display: inline;
}
```

After that, just remove your `float` and `left` attributes on your `ul` styling and set your `.nav-mains height` to `auto`.

Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/tzaz2d29/).

Comment: That was a better solution than mine, +1

Answer (score -1):

how about wrapping it in a div and using width:auto?
http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/width-auto/

Answer (score -1):

First, remove

```
left: 30%;
```

from

```
ul {...}
```

then change this:

```
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```